# Displaying only HTML Code on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a site developed in wordpress but something is wrong with the display. When I visit the URL, only HTML codes are displaying on the page.

Hope someone can help me here.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is like asking a mechanic: "I have a car and it's making a noise. What's wrong with it?"

Comment: Hi Diodeus, it is clear that only html codes/tags are displaying on the page. the content of the page is here: <!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <!--<![endif]--><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title> Site Title</title>............. it doesn't translate/convert the code to images, text, etc. can you help me?

Comment: Not really much information to go off here, but my guess would be that your CSS styles are not wrapped in style tags. Either that or you put the CSS into the wrong file.

Comment: the screenshot is only selected part of the page display. It is not CSS problem here. It displays all the html codes/tags in the page. It doesn't convert the html codes to images, text, etc.

Comment: It is very clear that the problem is displaying the html codes in the page. Read carefully the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- Update wordpress to the latest version.

Comment: I tried this steps and it is working. Thank you very much for this. W3 total cache is causing the problem.